# Why can't I create or pin a Folder to the Start menu?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I created a folder in the 'Open All Items' folder, at the same level as Programs, but it shows up under All Programs. I really want it to appear in the pinned area at the top of the start button menu. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**How to add "Pin to Start menu" option for folders**](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/pinfolder.htm) in Windows 7, XP and Vista

Comment: OK - 10 points for answering the exact question I asked. However, I now find that adding a Folder to the pinned area doesn't actually give me what I was looking for! In XP adding a folder to the start menu causes the items in the folder to appear as a dropdown menu - now in Win7 it opens an explorer window for the folder. Should I now ask another question?

Comment: "In XP adding a folder to the start menu causes the items in the folder to appear as a dropdown menu" i don't think so, a folder pinned to the left hand pane will open an explorer window in XP as well, if you wish to add a custom folder to the RIGHT hand pane (where it will expand) then you'll need a 3rd party application (e.g. WindowsBlinds)

Answer (score 0):

Right click the menu item you want to add, and choose "Pin to Start Menu". This applies when you are using the XP startmenu (which mean the one with "My Computer", "Documents", etc.)

If you are willing to switch to the Classic menu mode, then the menu item will automatically be shown at the top of the Start Menu.

[image]

To set the menu to the Classic version, follow these steps :

1. Right-click your Start button
2. Choose "Properties"
3. Check the radio button for "Classic Start Menu"
4. Click "OK"

There you go, Classic Menu back in action.

Comment: Just ran through some questions you asked before - it appears you are using Windows 7. In that case, the Classic Start Menu is no longer available. The correct way is the first way of right-clicking the menu item and choosing "Pin to Start Menu".

Comment: Molly's answer is the correct answer, question asked for _FOLDERS_ to be pinned to the start menu. Please do not upvote this answer.