# Is there a way for a folder pinned to the start menu have a sub menu listing files?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/38285/why-cant-i-create-or-pin-a-folder-to-the-start-menu) deals with how to pin folders in Windows 7 and Vista since its not enabled by default.

I would like to see if its possible to take this one step further and see if I can pin a folder and then somehow enable a submenu (similar to the "Task" list that appears for Chrome) but where the submenu contains the folder contents.

Any ideas?

Comment: Something like the one where we could add a folder shortcut in taskbar of windows xp and then clicking on it would display the subfolder contents ??

Comment: I never did that on Windows XP, but yes that sounds roughly similar. In my case I have a directory of RDC files for Remote Desktop, so would like quick access to launch any given connection.

Comment: Molly7244 answered this question in the comments section at the link you provided, not possible without 3rd party software such as WindowBlinds.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really possible in the way that I think you want it.

A workaround which does work is to right click on an empty spot and choose `Toolbars` > `New Toolbar`.

Choose a folder, then click `Select folder`.

You will now get a folder on the taskbar that can be expanded to view its contents.

[image]