# Custom App Folder

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, desktop-customization

I am trying to figure out if I can create a custom menu in the start menu. I would like to create a menu something like this, but for some custom apps that we use in house. Below are an example of a menu that I use to connect to different places and a example of the Programs I want to make a menu out of. As you can see I have made a start menu folder for them and created shortcuts to the real deal, and pinned that to the start menu, but I want to be able to select one app to open like how I would select one RDP file to open or one excel file.

EDIT: I want a way to pin multiple programs to the start menu as a menu. The fact that I have a folder with them is just my workaround thats closer than before.

Any suggestions?

[image: example RDP file menu] [image: These are the apps I want to have a menu of.]

Comment: The Pinned and Recent fly-outs are not just folder contents, software needs to be written to use them (more or less).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way for a folder pinned to the start menu have a sub menu listing files?](http://superuser.com/questions/274139/is-there-a-way-for-a-folder-pinned-to-the-start-menu-have-a-sub-menu-listing-fil)

Comment: in my specific example, yes duplicate. In my question, no. I want a way to pin multiple programs to the start menu as a menu. The fact that I have a folder with them is just my workaround thats closer than before.

Answer (score 2):

*Partial answer as I'm offering an alternative rather then a solution*

---

**2nd Attempt at giving a work around** (*First attempts below this*)

---

You could sacrifice your document link to be an expandable folder

> Start menu > right-click > Properties > Start menu > Customize

[image: Customize Start Menu]

> Right-click (Documents) > Properties > Select folder to display

[image: Customize documents]

End result:

[image: Start Menu]

---

**Original answer**

---

Windows 7 includes pin able objects onto the task bar, Now the cool thing about this is you can pin application relevant files to a pinned item

[image: Pinned items in a Pinned app on the task bar]

So from here you can build your pinned items the same way you would a folder.

Note: I'm not aware of a file count limit, This  doesn't mean there isn't one just that I don't know of one

Comment: Thanks, but no. This feature is called jump lists. But, since they don't open the same application with different input files, this only lets me pin the individual applications to the taskbar, not multiple into one object. If I could make a jump list that had the applications that would be great, but I havent been able to as of yet.

Comment: @PsychoData Appended with new solution

Comment: Okay, I read your new workaround. Not bad, I like my document folder, but I was willing to sacrifice my video folder. I keep all my video in pictures anyway. Video has the same options as documents, but alll the way at the bottom or the customize menu

Comment: As you can tell from all the black everywhere I'm at work but I find document perfect as I have my apps folder and my documents running from that context menu